# create appropriate model with linq and entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am quite new to `LINQ` and I am unable to get what I need.
At the end I need the following model:

```
public class MyModel {
     ... a quite long list of properties ...
     public List<SubModel> Submodels {get;set;}
}
```

MyModel contains a list of Submodel elements and there are about 50 submodels for each model.

To get this I am writing this query:

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext())
{
    var query = db.MyModels.As Queryable().Where(x => x.RevId == revId);
    var res = query.Join(db.MySubModels,
              pb => new { pb.Key, pb.RevId},
                f => new { f.Key, f.RevId}
              (pb, f) => new { MyModel = pb, Submodel = f });            
}
```

The above gives me anonymous type where each element has MyModel and Submodel, but this is not what I need. 
From this I somehow need to get the structure as described above. I believe I should somehow group data or something else.

**EDIT**
I need this, because later I have to add

a) one property to MyModel, that would do some calculations on "first element from List of MySubModels"

b)another property to MyModel, that would do some calculations on "third element from List of MySubModels"

etc.

P.S. I cannot use navigation propertu, because Join is done using Two column values (Key and RevId). Neither of them is unique in entity "MyModel" and "MySubModel", but combinatin of Key + RevId would be unieque.

Comment: if you have a foreign key relationship there should be navigation properties that have the data you need... look up the .Include() extension for linq to entities... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: tbh your current result may be the best solution if you have many myModels, as you avoid multiple queries. just ignore the extra data

Comment: I have modified a code, so now join is done using two columns. It was bug.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var db = new MyDataContext())
{
    var query = db.MyModels.As Queryable().Where(x => x.RevId == revId);
    var res = query
                .Join(db.MySubModels, pb => new { pb.Key, pb.RevId}, f => new { f.Key, f.RevId}, (pb, f) => new { MyModel = pb, Submodel = f })
                .AsEnumerable() //get the data and map objects
                .GroupBy(x => x.MyModel) //group them
                .Select(group => new { MyModel = group.Key, Submodels = group.Select(x => x.Submodel).ToList() });            
}
```

Comment: I am not having navigation properties. Basically because I need to join using two columns. Key is not unique. I have to join using "RevId + Key".

Comment: I have modified a code, so now join is done using two columns. It was bug.

Comment: @renathy ok, it's clearing up on my side now... does that fix that issue of yours on your side? if so just answer your own question and accept it (or delete the question... your call)

Comment: No it doesn't fix. It just show what I have now. But I need another structure. The result now is some anonymous type containing both Model and Submodels, I need to have Model with List of submodels. Later i need to take "first" submodel, "third" submodel and some others.

Comment: @renathy so what you need is simply a group by? changed the answer to match that...